Why port forwarding works only for some local devices?
I'm currently troubleshooting my network and one of the things I noticed is forwarding ports on my router (this one: https://www.tp-link.com/en/home-networking/wifi-router/archer-c6/v4/) seems to work only if I enter Device IP of my printer, but doesn't work on other devices it the same network.
This rule:

Results in this:

but this one:

results in:

I don't really know why my second test didn't work. Does target device need to have something enabled to be forwarded to? Does the router "care" to what kind of device it is forwarding packets?
I'd like to understand this topic better before I try resolving other issues. I'll add that I tried a different router and had same results.

Preliminary Check - Do you have a service running on port 5000 on other devices where you claim that port forwarding is not working? Just opening the port in router is one thing and for the remote site to detect, a service must be running (& listening) on the destination to acknowledge it. e.g. RDP, FTP etc etc just as an example

And of course Firewall (if any in any OS) must allow the access for that port!

No it's a random port number, but if that is true what service is my printer running on port 5000 for it to show as open? I tried different ports with same results, for instance I forwarded 80 or 443 using my PC's IP which were closed, but same ports were open if using printer's IP. I still don't understand the difference.

You can only port forward a port to a single device. So, if 192.168.1.6 had a service running on port 5000 and
192.168.1.8 does not that would be one reason but if you attempted to forward traffic on port 5000 to both 192.168.1.6 and 192.168.1.8 that would not work. Based on on insecure ports are on most printers, your printer is likely is listening on every port, so it can respond. This is way I perfer to use routers that support UPnP if there is something I really want to work, and I just make sure, I can patch the UPnP module myself.

I only ever had one rule active at a time, but I guess printer listening on every port might be a good explanation.

Most modern routers catch that as an error (Same port forwarded to multiple LAN IPs) and do not allow accepting such a rule in router's web interface.

Do you have Windows with Pro version on your PC/Laptop, if so simply enable Remote Desktop, disable firewall on that PC/Laptop as well in the router (for the time being) and set a rule to forward port TCP 3389. Check the results yourself. Also make sure to set DHCP reservation for that PC/Laptop in router's LAN section.

So I tried that on Windows 11, enabled Remote Desktop, disabled firewall on both PC and router, created rules for port 3389 and my PC IP and got a "port closed" result. But it was also closed on printer IP this time, so I'm thinking my ISP might not allow traffic on some ports to go through at all. I need to read more on that later. I guess this answers my questions for now.

While port forwarding worked on your printer, just make sure that your ISP gives your router a Public IP. If you are behind CGNAT & get a Private Non Routable IP, port forwarding will not work.
